# How to Work with Objects as Selection Option Values in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, html-select

Is there a way to pass an object as the value of a `<select> <option>` and then access the attributes of that object?

I’m trying to do something like this…

```
<div>
  <select v-model="product.carrier" class="custom-select">
    <option v-bind:value="{id: carrier.id, name: carrier.name}" v-for="carrier in carriers">
      {{ carrier.name }}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>

<div v-if="product.carrier.name === 'Custom'">
  <input type="text" v-model="product.custom_carrier">
</div>
```

I can get the ‘object’ from the option value, but can’t seem to access the `id` or `name` attributes on their own. I get an error trying to access the `name` attribute on `product.carrier`. I'm not sure if this just isn't possible or if I'm going about it the wrong way.

What I really need is the `<select>` to `v-model` the `product.carrier_id` but also use the `name` attribute to trigger the UI change since I don't want to use the ID from the 'Custom' option to do it.

I have the `product` available in the data object with the `carrier_id` attribute nested inside. Will this not work without specifically predefining `name` and `id` on the data object?

Maybe there's an easier way to achieve this that I'm not thinking of?

Comment: please provide your data object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `v-model="product.carrier_id"` and `:value="carrier.id"` and use a computed property to extract the name.

```
computed: {
  carrier_name() {
    const carrier = this.carriers.find(carrier => carrier.id === this.product.carrier_id)
    return carrier ? carrier.name : ''
  }
}
```

.

```
<div v-if="carrier_name === 'Custom'"> ...
```

Comment: Awesome! I made a small correction to your answer, but it works beautifully!